# Cannot update xcode on AppStore

Tags: macos, app-store, macos-high-sierra

I just upgraded from Sierra to High Sierra And I met this problem which is i cannot Update xcode. When i click on update it shows loading symbol on top starts animating and nothing happen.

[image]

I tried this:

```
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist RecommendedUpdates
sudo defaults delete /Library/Preferences/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate.plist DidRegisterLocalUpdates
sudo rm /Library/Updates
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/
```

Any help?

Comment: This is not a programming question, ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Re-login your apple id in App Store might help. If not, you can download the latest Xcode in developer website instead of updating.

https://developer.apple.com/downloads

Comment: I did a relog but still same thing, Thanks i'll download from that link.

Answer (score 6):

You actually doesn't have to go to developer website as @user9749232 said. If you move your current Xcode file from Applications(Finder -> Applications) to trash, you can then download the latest Xcode from AppStore itself. If you want your Xcode back, take it back from trash.

Answer (score 6):

For me it was due to OS version not being compatible with XCode version. I updated to the newest os and it worked.

Comment: Thanks it helped to understand the problem... Xcode 12.5 requires macOS 11.0 Big Sur and I was on 10.15.7 Catalina.

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the answers already given worked for me:
Delete the old version of Xcode, Sign out from the Appstore, Restart my mac, Sign in to Appstore and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

It've happened to me while a proxy software like Charles or Proxyman were running. Ensure there is no active ssl proxy running.

Answer (score 0):

Start the download. Wait for a substantial time with hardly any progress. Stop the download. Ensure all Xcode processes are closed down (restart if you are unsure).

Click download again.